# How can i change the color of "expand-more" icon on image below (Materialize framework)?

Tags: css, material-design, materialize, google-material-icons

I can't change the highlighted icon on image with class .material-icons
By default is black and i wanna change to white
The piece of code:

```
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col s12 m5">
                <div class="row card-panel teal">
                    <div class="row">
                        <form class="col s12">
                            <div class="input-field col s12">
                                <select>
                                    <option>Manhã</option>
                                    <option>Noite</option>
                                    <option>Indiferente</option>
                                </select>
                                <label>Disponibilidade</label>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[The icon that I want to change is the  red color circle highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bH0LW.png)

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using [Materialize's Select component](http://materializecss.com/forms.html)?

If so, try this:

```
.select-wrapper span.caret {
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
}
```